# What do I need to call CSBackupIsItemExcluded (probably from either Frameworks or Core Services) on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: c, linker-errors, macos-big-sur

Prior to updating to Big Sur today, I was able (on Mojave) to command-line compile/link a C program that calls CSBackupIsItemExcluded and CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation.

I achieved this (on Mojave) by linking:

```
cc cbget.o \
     /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Carbon \
     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation \
   -o cbget
```

I remember it taking me days to find this out (and find/download the files)
a year or two ago, and now I can't recall what I did :(
(Yeah, this time I'm taking better notes!)

If I try the above, it fails...those files/directories don't exist on Big Sur.

If I omit them, linking fails (expectedly) with:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation", referenced from:
_handle_file in cbget-b22970.o
"_CSBackupIsItemExcluded", referenced from:
_handle_file in cbget-b22970.o

I can't rely on XCode to magically find anything ... I'm compiling/linking from the
command line.

I know that CSBackupIsItemExcluded is still in the OS ... because the version of the program compiled/linked under Mojave that uses it runs just fine (and lets me toggle "don't backup" for files from the command line).

BTW, moving from Mojave to Big Sur, I was surprised to find "/usr/include" has disappeared,
and that the Apple-supplied "cc" magically knows to look at:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
for things like "#include <stdint.h>"

thanks for any pointers!
Stan

Answer (score 1):

I can believe that the Carbon framework might have disappeared (Apple deprecated it a long time ago) but not CoreFoundation.  CoreFoundation is one of the first things loaded when booting and a lot of other things depend on it.

Having said that though, if you do need Carbon (and it's still around) then I think you want to link against:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon`

rather than:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Carbon`

---

[`CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543314-cfurlcreatefromfilesystemreprese?language=objc) is part of CoreFoundation.

[`CSBackupIsItemExcluded`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1443602-csbackupisitemexcluded?language=objc) is part of CoreServices, so try linking with that.